# custom listing records using conditional

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

i need some help with my query, basically im trying to get all my order_items on the table, but i need to get all items by user_id, but there is a detail, i want to include also records that includes on a column more than 3 times the the same email on different users_id.

Ex:

```
table:

- id;
- user_id;
- email;
```

1- Get all records from mine (user_id); 2 - Get all records where on 3 differentes user_id have the same email value;

Here is my query:

```
$orders = OrderItem::select('email','user_id')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->distinct('email')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$orders = OrderItem::select(DB::raw('count(*) as email_count,email,user_id'))
 ->groupBy('email')
 ->where('email_count','>',2)
 ->orWhere('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
 ->get();
```

Comment: is complaining because the "count(*) as email_count", it sayys doent exist column email_count

Comment: I miss one `)` try now :<

Comment: strange, is still giving me the error, i put exactlly you have.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as email_count,email,user_id from `order_items` where `email_count` > 2 or `user_id` = 5 group by `email`)